# Как в JavaFX создать таблицу (TableView) содержащую кнопку?

Tags: java, javafx

Как создать таблицу одно из полей которой может содержать кнопку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо создать свою фабрику для ячеек и добавить ее в соотвествующую колонку. Вот таблица с двумя колонками в первой цифра, а во второй кнопка

```
public class ButtonInTable extends Application {
    private final TableView<Value> table = new TableView();
    private final ObservableList<Value> data
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Value("1"),
            new Value("2"),
            new Value("3"));


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(300);

        TableColumn numberCol = new TableColumn("Value");
        numberCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("value"));

        TableColumn buttonCol = new TableColumn("Button");
        buttonCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("BUTTON"));

        Callback<TableColumn<Value, String>, TableCell<Value, String>> cellFactory =
                new Callback<TableColumn<Value, String>, TableCell<Value, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public TableCell call(final TableColumn<Value, String> param) {
                        final TableCell<Value, String> cell = new TableCell<Value, String>() {

                            final Button btn = new Button("Button");

                            @Override
                            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                                if (empty) {
                                    setGraphic(null);
                                    setText(null);
                                } else {
                                    setGraphic(btn);
                                    setText(null);
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        return cell;
                    }
                };

        buttonCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(numberCol, buttonCol);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(table);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static class Value {

        private final SimpleStringProperty value;

        private Value(String value) {
            this.value = new SimpleStringProperty(value);
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value.get();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: не минусуйте просто так, поясните, чем ответ плох?

Comment: Все хорошо, спасибо)

Comment: это кто-то другой заминусовал. я думал узнать, что ему не понравилось.